# How do I identify a dynamic-id custom-type text field in WATiR?

Tags: ruby, watir

I have this input of type "Submit" that Watir cannot see. **I can identify it by ID**, but it doesn't turn up in browser.text_fields, or by any other idenfication method. The ID is dynamically generated so I cannot use it for testing. Any ideas on how to make this readable? I'm willing to change the WATiR source code if necessary.

```
<INPUT id=t8CPm value=Submit type=submit>
```

I have obviously tried `text_field(:value, 'Submit')` and `text_field(:type, 'Submit')`, and I get an "Unable to locate element" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try treating it as a button element?   Inputs of type submit are generally considered to be a button because the browser generally renders them that way.

try

```
 browser.button(:value, 'Submit').flash
```

and see if it works for you

Comment: input type submit corresponds to the button method

Comment: If there was a badge for "feel like a complete nob" I'd be awarded it this morning. Problem was that my code looks for z-buttons but my login page isn't ZK generated, it's ordinary HTML, so I assumed it wasn't a button. Lesson learned: never assume. Many thanks, works absolutely fine.

Comment: Glad to see my answer was right on the button.  (now hopefully there's no negative rep to be earned for bad puns)

Answer (score 0):

I changed INPUT_TYPES to ["text", "password", "textarea", "submit"] in the TextField class of input_elements.rb and there it was.

I should also probably edit the collections to read the type too.

Edit: I am an idiot and I didn't need to do this, but I'm leaving it here in case anyone else needs to identify a *real* dynamic-id custom-type text field, not a fake dynamic-id custom-type text field otherwise known in my particular case as a "button".